# How to add only one item from menu.xml to overflow menu in android?

Tags: android, xml, menu

I have menu xml file in menu->main.xml in which two item are available. I have two activities and i want to add this two item in overflow menu in first activity but in the second activity i want to add only one item in overflow menu.

**menu->main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_setting"
        android:title="@string/action_setting"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

So how to do that?

Comment: if you give `app:showAsAction="never"` means those menu option not at all visible in action bar ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it in two ways:

1. **Have separate menu XMLs for both activities**. one with both items and other with only one that you require.
2. remove the unneeded menu item in code inside 2nd activity, by overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu` e.g:

   ```
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
           menu.removeItem(R.id.action_setting);
           return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it programmatically by hiding it...For example

```
MenuItem refreshIcon = menu.findItem(R.id. action_refresh);
refreshIcon.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference to your menu item in `onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)` and update show as action as below in your second activity.

```
MenuItem menuitem = menu.finditem(your_id);
menuitem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`onCreateOptionsMenu`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)) that you'll have to override. You could try something like that, depending on what you need to show here:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.getItem(0).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
}
```